# the images keep on changing after getting loaded from firebase in the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a follow view controller which has a table view controller embedded in it.
When I try to load profile images from the firebase it loads well but keeps on interchanging images with rest of the profile images on scrolling down or up.
Also when I tap the table view cell  to follow that particular user the indication (a checkmark) appears on the fourth cell  too.
Is this a bug in xcode
I use Xcode 9.1 on  Mac os sierra 10.12.6

Comment: past your code so others can help to identify issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the images from the background, make sure you assign each image to correct cell. One way to do this is to create a custom class that holds an image and an unique id, whenever you want to assign an image to a cell, check the id first to make sure it's the right one.

About the checkmark bug, you can try to reset cell inside the `prepareForReuse()` function.

EDIT

Since you are using async, nothing guarantees that the images will be returned in order. As a result, to get the right image into the right cell you need to do something like this

```
//if the image is already fetched, you don't have to get it from firebase again
private var imageCache = [String:UIImage]()

//Create custom ImageView class that downloads image from url 
class CustomImageView: UIImageView{

var lastImageURL: String?

//call this function to get the right image with url
func setupWithImageURL(imageURL: String){
    self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    self.clipsToBounds = true

    //keep track of the url of the right image
    lastImageURL = imageURL

    //check if the image is already there
    if let cachedImage = imageCache[imageURL]{
        self.image = cachedImage
        return
    }

    //if no image, get it with url
    guard let url = URL(string: imageURL) else {return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        if let err = err{
            print("Unable to download data from database: ",err)
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {return}
        guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {return}
        imageCache[url.absoluteString] = image

        //if not the correct image, return and do nothing
        if (url.absoluteString != self.lastImageURL){
            return
        }

        //if the image is the correct one, set it to the imageView
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.image = image
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

}

Comment: it was working fine before i was really satisfied and moved on to the rest part of my project. I changed it's initial view controller to the one i wanted to work with. But after after some days when i re-run my app from the beginning i got this problem. Earlier i dealt this problem by rewriting the code clean and it worked (In this one too the problem came after some time). I have updated my question with the code

Comment: I edited my comment with code. Hope it solve your problem! @user00007

Comment: Wow! the images appear perfectly now but . I still notice some data being downloaded when i scroll down .Also the checkmark appears in the other cell too.

Comment: It's because of the way tableView reuse cell. Use a `set` of checkmark to keep track of the cell that you manually put checkmark on. Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, change the accessory type if the cell indexPath is not in the set.